# @AfterClass in SpringJUnit4ClassRunner (how to use beans in teardown)

Tags: java, spring, junit

I want to use beans in tear-down method in spring unit test (SpringJUnit4ClassRunner).
But this method (that is annotated with @AfterClass) should be static. What can be the solution?

example:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
//.. bla bla other annotations
public class Test{

@Autowired
private SomeClass some;

@AfterClass
public void tearDown(){
    //i want to use "some" bean here, 
    //but @AfterClass requires that the function will be static
    some.doSomething();
}

@Test
public void test(){
    //test something
}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

JUnit uses a new instance for each test method, so in `@AfterClass` execution the Test instance don't exists and you can't access to any member.

If you really need it, you could add a static member to the test class with the application context and set it manually using an `TestExecutionListener`

for example:

```
public class ExposeContextTestExecutionListener  extends AbstractTestExecutionListener {

    @Override
    public void afterTestClass(TestContext testContext) throws Exception {
        Field field = testContext.getTestClass().getDeclaredField("applicationContext");
        ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(field);
        field.set(null, testContext.getApplicationContext());
    }
}

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@TestExecutionListeners(listeners={ExposeContextTestExecutionListener.class})
@ContextConfiguration(locations="classpath:applicationContext.xml")
public class ExposeApplicationContextTest  {

    private static ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDown() {
        Assert.assertNotNull(applicationContext);
    }
}
```

Comment: That is why I like TestNG.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you want to use @After instead of @AfterClass. It isn't static.

Comment: Perhaps I don't want @After as I don't want to do heavy env preperation on every test class.